# Question about the linear preimage of a a affine vectorspace

Tags: linear-algebra

There is something I do not understand about this following statment:

Let $V,W$ be $F$  Vectorspaces and $L:V\rightarrow W$ a linearmap. If $U$ is a subspace in $W$ and $y$ a vector in $W$, then we have

$$\forall_{a\in L^{-1}\{y\}}:L^{-1}(y+U)=a + L^{-1}(U)\tag{*}$$

Below the statement there was the comment:

The preimage of each affine space is either a affine space or empty again.

I can see that if $\emptyset \neq L^{-1}\{y\}$ the identity above holds and that the preimage of an affine space is an affine space again. However I do not know how I can prove that if $L^{-1}\{y\}=\emptyset$ both sets are empty.

I need help how to argue that the right set in the equation $(*)$ is the empty set in this case. 
I also need help to prove that the left set is also the empty set in this case.

I have already tried a contradiction proof but no avail

Answer (score 0):

It starts by for all $a\in L^{-1}(y)$. This insures that both sets are not empty. since $a\in L^{-1}(y+U)$ since $L(a)=y\in y+U$, and $a\in a+L^{-1}(U)$ since $0\in L^{-1}(U)$.

Comment: But I want to show that the sets are empty if $L^{-1}(y)=\emptyset$